# OpenVpn + internet with no firewall and NAT

Tags: vpn, firewall, openvpn, nat

I have an openvpn running on a remote server through which multiple clients access internet. Now it's working via firewall and NAT/forwarding by iptables.

When I first set it up without firewall and forwarding/NAT, it didn't work, after connecting to the server, a client would stuck at "looking up the website..."

Is there any way to set it up without NAT and firewall/forwarding, though? What are procs and cons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to set up without NAT. You need a public IP address for every client you plan to have on the server simultaneously. Getting such an IP address space costs quite much nowadays, since IPv4 address space is almost exhausted.

Then you need to set up a bridge between interface having public IPv4 address space and the VPN link, so that VPN clients will be in the same broadcast domain.

Another option is to set up 1-1 NAT between VPN link private IP addresses and public IP addresses. However, that does need NAT, and doesn't exactly meet your requirements.

You should study fundamentals of IP networking and you would find out the answers yourself.

Comment: how about ipv6?

Comment: You can use bridging there.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to not use NAT on your OpenVPN server, you could try to configure http-proxy and put all http/https traffic trough proxy. But it requires additional configuration on client side, when NAT don't requires any configuration changes.

Comment: не могу плюсануть - кармы не хватает

Comment: @Jodarim255 Please reply in english. Thanks!

Comment: @EEAA he said that he couldn't vote up for my answer due low reputation.